# play the guitar vs play guitar

Tags: articles, definite-article, british-english, transatlantic-differences

I was taught that when we want to say *"produce sound on a musical instrument"*, we should always use the definite article before the instrument (*"play the guitar/piano/violin"*).

I did research on this, and I got the expected results from the dictionaries I use:

> Jean **plays the guitar** and her brother is on percussion. <sup>[Cambridge Dictionary - guitar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/guitar)</sup>
>
> He learned to **play the clarinet** at the age of ten. <sup>[Cambridge Dictionary - play](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play)</sup>
>
> He taught himself to **play the violin**. <sup>[Oxford Dictionary - play](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/play)</sup>

(particularly, they all pertain to *the skill* these people possess)

Then I came across [this thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/play-guitar-or-play-the-guitar-piano-violin-trombone-etc.424541/). There, some people said *"play guitar"* is more common in the USA while *"play the guitar"* is BrE.

One trustworthy American English dictionary provided the next examples:

> Howard Roberts **played guitar** and Schuur sang and played a Fender Rhodes piano. <sup>[vocabulary.com - guitar](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/guitar)</sup>
>
> I never thought about combining it with drag, ’cause to me, well, drag queens don’t **play guitar**. <sup>[vocabulary.com - guitar](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/guitar)</sup>

Moreover, I generated the ngram graph and noticed that the expressions using *the* are way more popular than those without the article:

[image: the ngram graph]

Now I am confused about which one is correct and whether they are both acceptable.

Comment: The context could be improved by supplementing the source of your dictionary quotes and specifying what dictionary you extract those sentences from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to refer to a thing not as a particular instance  but as the prototypical entity, as the class to which individual things of its type belong. Among them are the zero article and the definite article.

> Did you look in the dictionary?

That idiomatic use is not referring to a particular dictionary (M-W, Cambridge, Longman's, Oxford, whatever) but to the resource in the abstract, the prototypical notion of it, the book that *everyone* knows.

There are sometimes dialect preferences for the one or the other:

> They took him to hospital. <sup>BrE</sup>
>
> They took him to the hospital. <sup>AmE</sup>

These are therefore equally viable expressions of the fact that you can play that kind of musical instrument:

> I play the guitar.
>
> I play guitar.

Another use of the prototypical meaning is when a musical group, a band, *typically* includes a guitar.  In this meaning the sense borders on that of a *role*.

> He played guitar for that band at Woodstock.
>
> He plays washboard for the *Slow Pokes*.

And then we have the related phrases that ultimately derive from this idea of a typical role:

> They sang backup.
>
> He rode shotgun.
>
> He flies copilot for Qantas.

Comment: +1 for including the last part. There are several existing discussions here and elsewhere on this same topic, but nobody talked about _role_. Sheds new light on an old topic. "Shotgun" and "backup" in your examples sound adverbial.

Comment: @Eddie Kal: I am reluctant to classify **backup** in **sings backup** as adverbial.  I'd rather say it is a "role complement" or something like that, for if **backup** and **shotgun** are adverbial then is **washboard** also? *He **flies copilot** for Qantas*.